# GCP DataCatalog Linage API - Create Custom Linage

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform

We are using some custom spark process for certain ingestion and transformation. and So I wanted to utilize the Datacatalog Linage API to create our custom linage.

I am trying to follow mentioned documentation. However, not exactly able to figure out how to provide custom linage.

https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/lineage/latest/google.cloud.datacatalog.lineage_v1.types.CreateLineageEventRequest

This is what my code looks like.

```py
def sample_create_lineage_event():
    # Create a client
    client = lineage_v1.LineageClient()

    # Initialize request argument(s)
    request = lineage_v1.CreateLineageEventRequest(
        parent="my project id",
    )

    # Make the request
    response = client.create_lineage_event(request=request)

    client.create_process(request=request)

    # Handle the response
    print(response)
```

This gives following error

```
C:\Users\fki\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe C:/Users/fki/PycharmProjects/Demo/bq_linage/create_linage.py
E0529 10:27:44.489000000  6968 src/core/ext/transport/chttp2/transport/hpack_parser.cc:1227] Error parsing metadata: error=invalid value key=content-type value=text/html; charset=UTF-8
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\fki\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\google\api_core\grpc_helpers.py", line 65, in error_remapped_callable
    return callable_(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\fki\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\grpc\_channel.py", line 946, in __call__
    return _end_unary_response_blocking(state, call, False, None)
  File "C:\Users\fki\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\grpc\_channel.py", line 849, in _end_unary_response_blocking
    raise _InactiveRpcError(state)
grpc._channel._InactiveRpcError: <_InactiveRpcError of RPC that terminated with:
    status = StatusCode.UNIMPLEMENTED
    details = "Received http2 header with status: 404"
    debug_error_string = "UNKNOWN:Error received from peer ipv4:199.36.153.10:443 {created_time:"2023-05-29T14:27:44.4902741+00:00", grpc_status:12, grpc_message:"Received http2 header with status: 404"}"
>

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\fki\PycharmProjects\Demo\bq_linage\create_linage.py", line 42, in <module>
    sample_create_lineage_event()
  File "C:\Users\fki\PycharmProjects\Demo\bq_linage\create_linage.py", line 32, in sample_create_lineage_event
    response = client.create_lineage_event(request=request)
  File "C:\Users\fki\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\google\cloud\datacatalog\lineage_v1\services\lineage\client.py", line 1759, in create_lineage_event
    response = rpc(
  File "C:\Users\fki\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\google\api_core\gapic_v1\method.py", line 113, in __call__
    return wrapped_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\fki\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\google\api_core\grpc_helpers.py", line 67, in error_remapped_callable
    raise exceptions.from_grpc_error(exc) from exc
google.api_core.exceptions.MethodNotImplemented: 501 Received http2 header with status: 404

Process finished with exit code 1
```